# Django crash without message

Tags: django

I have a Django-project which was running fine, until I made "some changes" I don't remember exactly. Since that point, on every request, my project crashes silently:

```
$ ./manage.py runserver -v2
Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.1.1, using settings 'src.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

After I requested a page (admin oder frontend), it returns to the prompt. I did not find any other option to get verbose output than -v2 - is there any logfile I can use?

I'm using Django 1.1.1 on a Mac OS X 10.6 with virtualenv, Python 2.6

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution: Accidently, there was a recursive inclusion in a urls.py

Answer (score 0):

Since Django silent crashes are seldom and hard to troubleshoot I am going to add the reason it had for me: django-rest-knox introduced a breaking change in their package (which I did not notice when updating)

https://james1345.github.io/django-rest-knox/changelog/

so if your token is created with the old method and you have version 4 and up of knox installed, django exits without error message